# Printing a void* variable in C

Tags: c, printf, void-pointers, uint

Hi all I want to do a debug with printf. But I don't know how to print the "out" variable.

Before the return, I want to print this value, but its type is void* .

```
int 
hexstr2raw(char *in, void *out) {
    char c;
    uint32_t i = 0;
    uint8_t *b = (uint8_t*) out;
    while ((c = in[i]) != '\0') {
        uint8_t v;
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            v = c - '0';
        } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
            v = 10 + c - 'A';
        } else if (c >= 'a' || c <= 'f') {
            v = 10 + c - 'a';
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            b[i/2] = (v << 4);
            printf("c='%c' \t v='%u' \t b[i/2]='%u' \t i='%u'\n", c,v ,b[i/2], i);}
        else {
            b[i/2] |= v;
            printf("c='%c' \t v='%u' \t b[i/2]='%u' \t i='%u'\n", c,v ,b[i/2], i);}
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", out);
    return i;
}
```

How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data are you expecting `out` to point to?

Comment: Do you really want to print the pointer value itself? Considering what the code does, it seems more likely that you want to print the result, i.e. the generated bytes. See my answer for how to do that. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This:

```
uint8_t *b = (uint8_t*) out;
```

implies that `out` is in fact a pointer to `uint8_t`, so perhaps you want to print the data that's actually there. Also note that you don't need to cast from `void *` in C, so the cast is really pointless.

The code seems to be doing hex to binary conversion, storing the results at `out`. You can print the `i` generated bytes by doing:

```
int j;
for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)
  printf("%02x\n", ((uint8_t*) out)[j]);
```

The *pointer value* itself is rarely interesting, but you can print it with `printf("%p\n", out);`. The `%p` formatting specifier is for `void *`.

Comment: Isn't `uint8*` supposed to be `uint8_t` in your `printf` line?

Answer (score 64):

```
printf("%p\n", out);
```

is the correct way to print a `(void*)` pointer.

Comment: If you want to print the value rather than the pointer, then see unwind's answer.

Comment: I stored a constant character sequence in a void* and using %p% it is not printing the  string but what appears to be the address of the string

Answer (score 7):

The format specifier for printing void pointers using `printf` in C is `%p`. What usually gets printed is a hexadecimal representation of the pointer (although the standard says simply that it is an implementation defined character sequence defining a pointer).

Comment: Technically, it's up to the implementation to choose the "what gets printed", but I've never actually seen anything other than a simple hex number (despite rumours about AS/400s). :-)

Comment: @torek You're right, the standard says it's implementation defined. All implementations I've seen thus far decided to use hex, though :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hi, I am a little late here, but was hoping to ask you: I have seen from somewhere that printf("%p\n", ptr); should be printf("%p\n", (void *) ptr); or else we would get undefined behavior, is it true? If so, why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig Yes, this is true, unless `ptr` is a `char*`/`unsigned char*`, which are required by the standard to have the same representation as `void*`. Pointers to any other type may have a different layout in memory (this is rare, but it may happen). That is why an explicit conversion is required.